# Delete Button in Visualforce not working in Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning, button

I have a Visualforce page with a standard controller and an extension.

It has a delete button:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!delete}" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"/>
```

In Classic it works as expected - it returns to the list page.

In Lightning, after confirming the 'Are you sure?' dialog, I get an error page:

```
Data Not Available

The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our support page.
```

The object has been deleted, as expected, but it seems that LEX tries to return to the deleted object page, which obviously fails.

How can I change this VF page to work in both Classic and Lightning?

Comment: How are you directing users to this page? Is it a custom button/action on the record?

Comment: How does `<apex:commandButton`  work in lightning? where is it placed in?